# "C'est aller au delà."

Tags: vocabulaire

L'expression:

> c’est aller au delà.

veut dire quoi dans ce contexte:

> Être ultra, **c’est aller au delà**. C’est attaquer le sceptre au nom du trône et la mitre au nom de l’autel ; c’est malmener la chose qu’on traîne ; c’est ruer dans l’attelage ; c’est chicaner le bûcher sur le degré de cuisson des hérétiques ; c’est reprocher à l’idole son peu d’idolâtrie ; c’est insulter par excès de respect ; c’est trouver dans le pape pas assez de papisme, dans le roi pas assez de royauté, et trop de lumière à la nuit ; c’est être mécontent de l’albâtre, de la neige, du cygne et du lys au nom de la blancheur ; c’est être partisan des choses au point d’en devenir l’ennemi ; c’est être si fort pour, qu’on est contre.

Source:[Les Misérables — Tome III : Marius (1862)](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables/Tome_3/Livre_3/03)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans ce contexte, **c’est aller au delà** signifie en faire trop jusqu'à ce que cela devienne absurde :

> insulter par excès de respect

ou extrême (au sens de l'extrémisme politique contemporain)

> c’est trouver dans [..] le roi pas assez de royauté*.

Le mot équivalent pourrait être **fanatisme** :

Dans *Figuring Transcendance in Les Misérables* de K. M. GrossMan (p105), à propos du passage cité :

> Hugo explores here in greater depth [...] Javert's fanaticism.

*Hugo explore ici plus profondément le fanatisme de Javert.*

Comment: Oui, *aller au delà*, c'est *dépasser les bornes*.

Answer (score 2):

Je crois que dans ce contexte la signification serait de s'élever, de dépasser le commun